# How can I solve this limit of a function defined in $R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to find out for which $\alpha>0$ this limit equals to $0$:
$$\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{1+\sin(|x|^\alpha y)-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}$$
I tried to separate it in two parts:
$$\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}+\frac{\sin(|x|^\alpha y)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}$$
Now the first term doesn't depend on $\alpha$ and it is asymptotic to:
$$\frac{1-1+\frac{(x^2+y^4)^2}{2}}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}=\frac{(x^2+y^4)^{1/2}}{2}$$
So this term tends to $0$ when $(x, y)$ tends to $(0, 0)$.

Then I tried to study the other term using the squeeze theorem in this way:
$$0\le \left \vert \frac{\sin(|x|^\alpha y)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}} \right\vert \le \left \vert \frac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+(y^2)^2)^{3/2}} \right\vert \le \left \vert \frac{|x|^\alpha y}{(2|x||y|^2)^{3/2}} \right\vert \le \frac{|x|^{\alpha-3/2}}{|y|^2} $$
At this point I thought that if x goes to $0$ faster than y, then the whole thing tends to $0$: meaning, I set $\alpha - \frac{3}{2} > 2$ and therefore $\alpha > \frac{7}{2}$.

Honestly I see so many possible mistakes in this procedure, but I couldn't find another way to solve this problem, so I'd like to know if this is correct, and if not, how should I have done it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It results that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{1+\sin(|x|^\alpha y)-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}=$

$=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{1-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}+ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sin(|x|^\alpha y)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}=$

$=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^4}\cdot\!\!\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{1-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}+\\[3pt]\quad+ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sin(|x|^\alpha y)}{|x|^\alpha y}\cdot\!\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}\,.$

By using the following notable limits

$\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos z}{z^2}=\dfrac12\;\;$ and $\;\;\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{\sin z}z=1\;,\;$ we get that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\!\!\!\dfrac{1-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}=\dfrac12\;$ and $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\!\!\!\dfrac{\sin(|x|^\alpha y)}{|x|^\alpha y}=1\;,$

moreover, it is easy to show that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^4}=0\;.$

Let $\;\varphi:(-\infty,+\infty)\to\Bbb R\;$ be the function defined as follows :

$\varphi(z)=\dfrac z{\left(1+z^4\right)^{3/2}}\quad$ for any $\;z\in\Bbb R\,.$

It results that

$\begin{align}\big|\varphi(z)\big|&=\dfrac{|z|}{\left(1+z^4\right)^{3/2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{z^2}{\left(1+z^4\right)^3}}\leqslant\sqrt{\dfrac{\frac12\left(1+z^4\right)}{\left(1+z^4\right)^3}}=\\&=\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac12}}{1+z^4}\leqslant\sqrt{\dfrac12}<1\;\;,\quad\text{ for any }z\in\Bbb R\,.\end{align}$

Now, we will prove that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}=\begin{cases}\text{does not exist}&\text{if }\,0<\alpha\leqslant\dfrac52\\[3pt]0&\text{if }\,\alpha>\dfrac52\;\;.\end{cases}$

It results that

$\begin{align}\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}&=\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{\left|x\right|^3\left(1+\frac{y^4}{x^2}\right)^{3/2}}=\dfrac{|x|^{\alpha-\frac52}\frac y{\sqrt{|x|}}}{\left[1+\left(\!\frac y{\sqrt{|x|}}\!\right)^{\!4}\right]^{3/2}}=\\[3pt]&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=|x|^{\alpha-\frac52}\!\cdot\!\varphi\left(\!\frac y{\sqrt{|x|}}\!\right)\;\;\text{ for any }\,x,y\in\Bbb R\,\land\,x\neq0\;.\end{align}$

If $\;0<\alpha\leqslant\dfrac52\,,\;$ then

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)\\y=\pm\sqrt{|x|}}\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}=\begin{cases}\;\pm\infty&\text{if }\,0<\alpha<\dfrac52\\[3pt]\varphi(\pm1)=\pm\dfrac1{2^{3/2}}&\text{if }\,\alpha=\dfrac52\end{cases}$

consequently,

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}\quad$ does not exists if $\;0<\alpha\leqslant\dfrac52\,.$

On the other hand, if $\;\alpha>\dfrac52\,,\;$ then

$\left|\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}\right|=\begin{cases}|x|^{\alpha-\frac52}\!\cdot\!\left|\varphi\left(\!\frac y{\sqrt{|x|}}\!\right)\right|<|x|^{\alpha-\frac52}&\text{if }\,x\neq0\\[3pt]\;0&\text{if }\,x=0\end{cases}$

and, since $\,\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|x|^{\alpha-\frac52}=0\;,\;$ by using Squeeze Theorem, we get that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}=0\,.$

Hence ,

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\!\!\!\!\dfrac{1+\sin(|x|^\alpha y)-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}}=0\;\;$ for any $\,\alpha>\dfrac52\,.$

Comment: congrats for hitting 9k

Comment: @SineoftheTime, thank you very much !

Comment: @Angelo thank you very much, you explanation was very clear and it really helped